# Finding a unique fixed point for a dynamical system

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Looking to show that (0,0) is a unique fixed point of the following system:
$$
\dot{x}=-x-3y^2 \\
\dot{y}=xy-y^3
$$

Comment: waht have you done so fare?

Comment: The question is looking for a Lyapunov function for the system which I think I have but also wants you to verify that (0,0) is a unique fixed point and I'm not sure how to get started with that \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have as equations for stationary points
$$
0=-x-3y^2\\
0=y(x-y^2).
$$
It is easy to see that this has only one solution.